# How can this be valid PHP code? And what can be done to avoid it?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I checked my project wide error logs today and found a plethora of these notices:

> "Undefined index: myVar in /myScript.php on line 3"

It took me ages to find the error. So here it is, condensed down to just 4 lines of code (originally it was a little bit more than that). **I just did not see the semicolon!**

```
if (isset($_POST['myVar']));
{
    echo $_POST['myVar'];
}
```

In other cases where things are prone to errors I have my ways. Like in this example where I falsly use "=" instead of "==":

```
if ($myVar = 5) {} // valid PHP but sooo wrong...
if (5 = $myVar) {} // parser error warns me of my own mistakes
```

**So what could I have done better in above example to not let the semicolon thing happen?**

Comment: *"How can this be valid PHP code?"* It's not, well not for this. You're assigning instead of comparing using `if ($myVar = 5) {}` use 2x `==` - *"So what could I have done better in above example to not let the semicolon thing happen?"* Do it the way it's supposed to be and the way it was conceived; don't try and re-invent the wheel.

Comment: what you have to do is focus on the task at hand

Comment: Be sincere while coding.:-p

Comment: Use formating tool (from Netbeans for example)

Comment: Plus, if you're looking to see "how to throw an error", add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` if error reporting isn't on by default.

Comment: @Fred-ii- , there is no syntax error, just semicolon after condition.

Comment: @sectus Ok that one escaped me. Thanks for the notice. I will re-phrase.

Comment: The semi-colon tells PHP "here's a semi-colon, stop this processing  and go on with the next command". Since it told PHP to stop and continue on to the next line, it throws an "undefined index" error. The semi-colon defines an end of execution. Have a read => http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Comment: _“So what could I have done better in above example to not let the semicolon thing happen?”_ – it simply _is_ valid syntax, so there is nothing to actually complain about here. What you could have done better would maybe be letting errors get _displayed_ straight away during development – that way, you at least would have caught this earlier, and not eons later when you _finally_ thought, _“oh, let’s look into the error log for once”_ And yes, some IDEs have mechanisms to alert you to things like this that could be problematic and _might_ be unintended – so go get a proper one.

Comment: *"Each PHP statement is **terminated** by semicolon"* Source => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_syntax_and_semantics

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['myVar']));` I think I've already outlined this with the analogy shown further up but will elaborate a bit more. This translates to "if myVar is set (which mostly could be), then stop because there's a semi-colon, terminate this statement". Since it stops there, the next line is still executed but it's trying to echo a POST variable and because PHP was already done with the previous line, it can't echo it because there is nothing to support it. As a developer, you should be able to know the differences regarding conditional statements and regular echos.

Comment: *Furthermore,* I think your question is invalid. `"Undefined index: myVar in /myScript.php on line 3"` line 3 eh? Line 3 is `echo $_POST['myVar'];` how could that possibly run when there's no `<?php` tag? Had it been there, line 3 would be an opening brace. Had this been valid code, and that error reporting were on, you'd be getting an `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'myVar' (T_STRING)` error message and not the error you've stated to be. So personally, I think your question is bogus and you've taken us all for a ride.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve your coding style.

The PSR-2 style does not allow putting the curly braces on a new line when using IF, they have to be on the same line as IF, separated with a space.

```
if (isset($_POST['myVar'])); {
    echo $_POST['myVar'];
}
```

And this looks a little bit more suspicious than your code. Still enough characters to confuse the searching eye, but you usually do not expect a semicolon between parentheses and curly braces of an IF statement.

Coding style is all about making errors look like errors and stand out prominently. While this one really is valid syntax, it would look strange enough to spot the error, because semicolons belong at the end of a line.

If you'd format your code automatically, you'd get your original code back, making you wonder why the curly brace went to the next line...

Comment: Well, now that's the first time I read a convincing argument why to use PSR-2 :-) I still won't because my whole project (the only one for years now) is using new lines before the bracket. But still I would be convinced if starting out from the beginning.

Also thanx for the idea to auto format the code when looking for errors. That's half way to debugging but still a valid answer (as I was asking for the before-debugging part). Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question, this is a matter of either using an IDE that gives you better hints, or simply debugging better so it doesn't take you ages. You could also turn on error messages so you get an immediate error rather than having to check logs.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then use the error message hint to help isolate the problem. It said the error was on line 3 and that `myVar` was undefined, so you should really focus on line 3 or what is immediately before it and be looking as to why an undefined variable is being used.

I'm guessing after this situation, you'll notice the semi colon quicker.